# Accessing task management API with PHP using cURL

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm attempting to access an API for a task management system (Nozbe to be exact) that is outlined here: http://www.nozbe.com/api

If I go in my browser and access the URL it returns the correct json response:
{"response":"644a40436"}

However, when I attempt to access this URL with cURL in PHP, it doesn't create the note like it would if I accessed it manually in my browser.

The normal method is outlined below:
http://www.nozbe.com/api/newnote/name-test/body-test/project_id-c4ca1/context_id-c4ca1/key-1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j1k2l3m4n5o6

```
$api_key                = "INSERTAPIKEYHERE";
$project_id             = "73d173457";

$eventtitle             = "Testing";

$descrip                = "This is a test";


$url                    = "http://www.nozbe.com/api/newnote/name-$eventtitle/body-$descrip/project_id-$project_id/key-$api_key";

echo "$url<br/><br/>";

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Does anyone have any advice or pointers as to why this isn't working? I know it's probably a pretty obscure API I'm attempting to access.

Comment: What does the API call return? It may be giving you an error message that will indicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the API says that the body and the like must be URL-encoded. Instead, you have spaces in your URL. Try running urlencode on the arguments before placing them into the URL.

Comment: @jaytr0n: if an answer solves your problem, be sure to click the check mark next to it to mark the question as answered :)